# fetch all rows if where field is empty in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where-clause

I am working with a sql query where I have fields set dynamically but few of the fields values can be null,In case its null I want to fetch all the records with that column data.

like:

```
Select * from users where name=:name and class=:class;
```

Now suppose I have got value of only name variable and not the class,So now As class variable is not there It will give a error but I want to fetch users with all the classes in that case?

I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("name", request.params.name);
//run the query
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with MySQL when you need something in PostgreSQL?

Comment: adding those next

Comment: will retrieve all value If parameter value is null?

Answer (score 2):

If parameter value is NULL then retrieve all value.

```
-- PostgreSQL
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE (name = param_name OR param_name IS NULL) 
    AND (class = param_class OR param_class IS NULL);
```

Comment: That will work, but won't perform well.

Comment: I agree with @LaurenzAlbe. Even tough this solution will provide the correct result, it's a terrible workaroud if the table has many rows. The performance could become really bad.

Comment: Actually retrieve all rows form large table always affects the performance. I've write this query according to questioner need.